# Auto-Layout problems with NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am building collection view where sections have vertical scrolled content (with infinite scroll view) and all the sections are placed next to each other (here's also used infinite scroll view, but horizontal). It looks like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqbuH.png).

I am facing with several problems:

1. The header view is below the collection view in views hierarchy (it isn't `hidden` nor `enabled`, it's just covered by the rest of the collection view), offsetting section doesn't help, because it's hidden below the whole collection view, not only the section. Here's [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QK7w.png), where on the most right are first subviews in view's hierarchy and on the left the last (with cutted non-related views in back).
2. My items have dynamically generated size (implemented with auto-layout in `.xib` file), but compositional layout's `.estimated()` value isn't changed per given height of the cell's content (width stays same for all cells).

Here's my code:

```swift
    func createCompositionalLayout() -> NSCollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(300), heightDimension: .estimated(170))
        
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(300), heightDimension: .estimated(150))
        
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 30
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        let layoutSectionHeaderItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(300), heightDimension: .absolute(200))
        let layoutSectionHeaderItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: layoutSectionHeaderItemSize, elementKind: NSCollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [layoutSectionHeaderItem]

        
        let configuration = NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        configuration.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        configuration.interSectionSpacing = 30
    
        let layout = NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: configuration)
        
        return layout
    }
```